# Duplicate code while using interfaces / inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a situation concerning inheritance that I find difficult to find a good OO design for.

Basically I have the following situation:

[image: Structure]

Webservice is an abstract class that holds all generic functions for all webservices.
Then most webservices are split between being a promotional webservice (Retrieving promotional data) or being able to retrieve information about persons (PersonWebservice). These are also abstract because they hold generic implementations that are true for all the children (Think extra processing after getting the data). The children only hold the functions and implementations specific to that child webservice.

So far so good... but... I have one webservice (Webservice E) that messes with this whole design... Because this webservice is both a person webservice and a promo webservice... As far as I can see there is not really an option of placing a super class between Webservice and Promo/Person webservices. It really is just the case that most webservices have limited functionality while this Webservice E can do both.

I have thought about using interfaces but then I will have to implement all the generic code multiple times in the children or I have to extend one of the super classes and duplicate half of the generic code of the other branch, which does not sound like a good design to me...

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions what a good approach could be to solve such a design/structure problem while avoiding as much duplicate code as possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean "a super class between them" ? you can put one 'above' them

Comment: Yes sorry that's what I mean. As in WebService -> Superclass new -> Promo/PersonWebservice. However, I find it difficult to see any 'shared' properties between Promo and Person webservice. It is more that they have the ability to do 1 of them or both.

Comment: this does point to a code smell, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle, why does Webservice E have multiple responsibilities, is there no way to split those?

Comment: @Yogesh_D: Maybe you are right and am I thinking to much centered on the webservice itself. Maybe I should actually make 2 separate implementations of Webservice E, one of them extending promo webservice the other person webservice, while it is in the real world actually the same webservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical thing that comes to mind: [FCoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - favor composition over inheritance.

You could:

- create *interfaces* that wrap around the "core functionality"
- have those existing classes implement them accordingly
- and WebServiceImpl also implements the interface - by *delegating* to an *instance* of those other classes

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can see there is not really an option of placing a super class between Webservice and Promo/Person webservices. It really is just the case that most webservices have limited functionality while this Webservice E can do both.

Why would that be? You can put your `WebService E` as a class implementing `WebService`, then have `Promotional Webservice` and `Person Webservice` extends it, override the method that must be abstrat as abstract.

A simple example of abstracting a method:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```